# Corefile to return fix address

Tags: coredns, core-file

I want to always return a certain address for a domain with CoreDNS. My expectation would be to have some such section on `Corefile`:

```
domain.of.mine {
  address 192.168.122.122 #this of course doesn't work
}
```

So, I'd always answer with that address for name in the domain. 
My question is: What's the easiest way to achieve this with CoreDNS?

I've looked through [the available plugins](https://coredns.io/plugins/) and the one that sounded the closes to what I want was the [template plugin](https://coredns.io/plugins/template/), but I have a feeling there should be an easier way to this.

Answer (score 1):

What I came up with was using the `template` plugin:

```
domain.of.mine {
  template ANY ANY {
    answer "{{ .Name }} 60 {{ .Class }} {{ .Type }} 192.168.122.122"
  }
}
```

It will effectively respond to any request with the specified address.